# Nested summation with varying limits

Tags: summation

I have a function: 
$$\rho(i,j)\ \ \ \ \textrm{for}\ i=1,\ldots,n\ \textrm{and}\ j=1,\ldots, m$$
I can write a summation $\rho(i,j)$ for all values of $i$ and $j$:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \rho(i,j) $$
How can I write this summation if m is not the same for each value of i? E.g. for $i=1$, $m=a$, but for $i=2$, $m=b$.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: a and b are non-zero scalars. I just wanted to indicate they are different values, is there a clearer notation I can change it to?

Comment: $m_i$, where $m = [a, b, \dots ]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it as: $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{m_i} \rho(i, j) $$